# Two Linux distros with shared /home – will they share user accounts automatically?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, debian, multi-boot

I'm running a dual boot Linux system and recently installed Debian Jessie onto my computer. I mounted my existing `/home` partition, but when the computer boots to login, my user account is missing. The default account created during setup is present, but the existing account (created with Ubuntu on the same machine) is not.

When I boot to Ubuntu the opposite occurs: my existing account is present, but the Debian default account is not.

The strangest bit of all this is that `dir /home` shows both account folders, and file explorer shows all files present. I have no idea what could be causing the error.

Comment: I have deleted my comments and wrote an answer instead, therefore some of your comments now seem slightly enigmatic. You may want to delete them as well to keep the question tidy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Users are defined in `/etc/passwd` file, not by their `/home/*/` directories. Your assumption seems to be: *one OS should automagically add a user created in the other* – and it is wrong.

You have separate `/etc/` (so `/etc/passwd` also) for every OS. Making a single common `/etc/` is not a good idea. Making a single common `/home/` can be done but there are pitfalls. The subject is discussed here: *[Different linux distros sharing the same `/home` folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6344/108618)*. The main concerns (from various answers there) are:

> - UID and GID must be the same on each distribution for the certain user(s).
> - Two versions of the same program reading and writing the same config files could result in problems, e.g. if the newer version writes something that the older version does not understand.

As with everything it is good to know what you are doing. Useful commands and subjects to gain some insight:

- `man 5 passwd`
- `man adduser`
- `man vigr`
- what is UID?
- what is GID?
- ownership and permissions in Linux.

Comment: And of course, when you are dealing with Debian, older versions of software is par for the course... It's the price you pay for its stability (in terms of not introducing breaking changes, not necessarily in terms of the software not having any bugs).

Comment: More to this, what users are available for logging in is actually determined using a special subsystem called `PAM`, and the `/etc/passwd` is just the most often used "backend" of it. Another backend widely used in enterprise is LDAP which contains the information on user accounts in a centralized database. With LDAP logins, it's even customary to have autocreation of the user's home directories (out of a special "skeleton") when they log into the given computer for the first time.